# usePagination custom-hooks with material-ui using next and prev functions in Pagination component as props

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui, react-hooks

i have used a custom-hook for pagination with material-ui. the component works fine for first page but  call for  `next()` , `prev()` and `jump()`does not work.i have tried to pass `next={next}` as props .i have read the api documentation from [here](https://material-ui.com/api/pagination/) but could not find proper way to call above functions.
here is code for usePagination.jsx custom-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function usePagination(data, itemsPerPage) {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage);

    function currentData() {
      const begin = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
      const end = begin + itemsPerPage;
      return data.slice(begin, end);
    }

    function next() {
      setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(currentPage + 1, maxPage));
    }

    function prev() {
      setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.max(currentPage - 1, 1));
    }

    function jump(page) {
      const pageNumber = Math.max(1, page);
      setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(pageNumber, maxPage));
    }

    return {
      next, prev, jump, currentData,
      currentPage, maxPage
    };
}

export default usePagination;
```

here is my Courses.jsx where i want to show list of courses with pagination.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CourseList from "./CourseList" ;
import usePagination from "./usePagination";
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import CourseForm from "./CourseForm";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import  { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));


  const Courses =(props)=> {


    const classes = useStyles();

      useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllCourses()


        }, [])
           // pagination code here
          const { next, prev,
             jump, currentData,
            currentPage, maxPage }
             =usePagination(props.courseList,4);

             console.log("total pages:"+ maxPage)

        return( 
           <div >

        <CourseList
             courseList={currentData()}

             deleteCourse={props.deleteCourse}
             createCourse={props.createCourse}
             updateCourse={props.updateCourse}


               />



              <div className={classes.root}>

      <Pagination count={maxPage}

       color="primary" />

    </div> 
    </div> 
                );    

    }
    const mapStateToProps= (state) =>({
        courseList:state.course.list


    })
    const mapActionToProps={
        fetchAllCourses:actions.fetchAll,
        deleteCourse:actions.Delete,
        createCourse:actions.create,
        updateCourse:actions.update,
        fetchCourse:actions.fetchById

           }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionToProps)(Courses);
```

thanks in advance for help.

Comment: See working example here using react hooks + material-ui + your usePagination custom hook: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-material-ui-pagination-example-trp9o

Comment: Hi @DannyZ  good effort .i also implemented hooks in my project which will be online soon.if you submit as answer i could accept it for your points.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a stateful hook that provides click handlers to manage page changes. Then you put it inside a React component and use it to drive a MUI `Pagination` component.

The point is that a MUI `Pagination` is perfectly equipped with its own click handlers that are there to manage... page changes! The logic is already inside, and your work is unnecessary.

Just for completeness, Material-UI offers out-of-the-box a hook `usePagination` which does what you're trying to achieve. The main user of this hook is... `Pagination`.

MUI `usePagination` allows to specify completely the look & feel of a pagination bar.

There are basic examples of `usePagination` usage [for version 5](https://mui.com/components/pagination/#usepagination) and [for version 4](https://v4.mui.com/components/pagination/#usepagination).

Source code for v.5 is [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/usePagination/usePagination.js).

The best way to fully understand the logic of this hook is to check its [unit tests](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/usePagination/usePagination.test.js).